# cookie is not getting persisted in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

In the code below, i m trying to make a persistent cookie. The cookie is getting created successfully. It stores the name specified in the textbox and when the page is reloaded the alert box comes as "welcome back nameFromTextBox". But, as the browser session ends, as i close the browser and loads the page again the cookie is deleted. I want to make a cookie which will last whenever i open the page. Is it the correct way i m doing it? Whats missing?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = function()
        {
            if(document.cookie.length!=0)
            {
                var cook = document.cookie.split("=");
                document.getElementById("txt").value=cook[1];
                alert("Welcome back " + cook[1]);
            }
        }

        function mname()
        {
            var tdate = new Date();
            tdate.setDate(tdate.getDate()+1);
            var uname = document.getElementById("txt").value;
            document.cookie="name=" + uname + ";expires=tdate.toUTCString();";
            alert("cookie created as " + document.cookie );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Please enter your name-<br>
    <input type="text" id="txt" /><br>
    <button onclick="mname()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Look at the pretty colors in your question, and it should be obvious why the date part of the cookie isn't working

Comment: why isn't it working?? @adeneo

Comment: Because `tdate.toUTCString();` is **literally a string**, that's why it's red, and not black in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in this line

```
document.cookie="name=" + uname + ";expires=tdate.toUTCString();";
```

correction

```
document.cookie="name=" + uname + ";expires=" + tdate.toUTCString();
```

and it works....